# Firestore Recycler loads in one page (instance) but not another

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a restaurant app with a food page that is populated by 2 Firestore recycler views. The weird this is one restaurant loads everything normal but the others fail. I have gone over the database and everything seems fine there but it just won't work. here are some images showing the differences:
PS how do i resize uploaded images?

[image: As you can see there is nothing here] [image: But this one loads]

As you can see there is no size option in the first pic but the 2nd pic has them.

here is my code:

the page:

```
    private void setUpSizes() {
        if (getIntent() != null)
            foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("foodid");
            Log.d("TAG", "setUpSizes: "+foodId);

        if (!foodId.isEmpty() && foodId != null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "setUpSizes: "+foodId);
            Query foodSizes = db.collectionGroup("sizes").whereEqualTo("id", foodId);

            FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SizeOptionsModel> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<SizeOptionsModel>()
                    .setQuery(foodSizes, SizeOptionsModel.class)
                    .build();

            mSelectedFoodSizeAdapter = new SizeOptionsAdapter(options);

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.size_recycler);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mSelectedFoodSizeAdapter);
            


        }

    }

      }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mSelectedFoodExtrasAdapter.startListening();
        mSelectedFoodSizeAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mSelectedFoodExtrasAdapter.stopListening();
        mSelectedFoodSizeAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

the adapter:

```
    private FoodSizesHolder holder;


    private int mSelectedItem = -1;

    private Context context;


    public String getPriceFromAdapter() {
        return priceFromAdapter;
    }

    private String priceFromAdapter;

    public SizeOptionsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<SizeOptionsModel> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodSizesHolder holder, int position, @NonNull SizeOptionsModel model) {
        holder.food_size.setText(model.getName());
        holder.food_size_price.setText(model.getPrice());

        //Allow only one radio button to be checked
        holder.food_size.setChecked(position == mSelectedItem);
        //Auto select the first item
    
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return super.getItemCount();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FoodSizesHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sizes_item, parent, false);
        return new FoodSizesHolder(v);
    }


    class FoodSizesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        RadioButton food_size;
        TextView food_size_price;

        public FoodSizesHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            food_size = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sizes_checkbox);
            food_size_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sizes_prices);
            if (food_size.isChecked()){
                priceFromAdapter = String.valueOf(food_size_price.getText());
            }

                }
            });

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted **almost 300 lines of code** for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you, i leaned out the code

Comment: It's still a lot of unrelated code, Emil. I am still not clear *what* the exact issue is and what the *expected* behavior was...